# PHP mssql_query upgrade 2500 connections advice

Tags: php, sql-server, oop, pdo, odbc

I have 3 servers, about ten years of procedural code that was developed using the mssql_query function in php which to my understanding is deprecated beyond 5.3 and I am wondering what is the best way to update all of this code.

I have created a database wrapper class and started running all of my sql statements through it instead of calling the PHP functions now but that doesn't help me for any of the older applications that would take too long to update.

I have thought about creating a php 5.5 or above server and slowly migrating applications over to it but that sounds like an absolute mess because there is a ton of classes that all applications rely upon.

*Any advice would be much appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

Both extensions are fairly compatible, so it should be possible to upgrade an existing application to MySQLi without too much trouble.

It is not as easy as `sed -e 's/mysql_/mysqli_/g'`, but there are automated tools for this. 
For example, there's this one: **https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool** which is a fork of a tool [originally created by MySQL/Oracle themselves](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi).

I assume that you have some sort of VCS, but if not, you should make a copy of the old code before applying the script, and compare the source trees afterwards with `diff -ur` or something similar, to make sure that all modifications are correct.